# CiviCRM database upgrade

Tags: upgrade, installation

I have a Joomla! CiviCRM installation (civi version 5.10.4). This has some functionality issues (reports do not work correctly). I no longer need Joomla! so is there a route to install latest CiviCRM and then put the existing (but updated) CiviCRM database into it?

I dont know if the issue with the current installation is code or data. Doing this will eliminate any code issue.

Any suggestions on how to do this or alternative approaches are very welcome.

many thanks
Dave

Comment: See https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/misc/switch-servers/

Comment: thanks, i had read that article. I am not sure how it helps this scenario. I cant see how it covers upgrading the existing database into a new installation. Thinking about it i could copy the existing CiviCRM and upgrade that to the latest version. Also create a new empty installation and then copy the database from my updated instance to the empty instance. That should work - at least it should prove if the issues with my current installation is caused by corrupted code or data

Answer (score 2):

CiviCRM sits on top of Joomla, WordPress, Drupal or Backdrop so even if you don't need the content of your current Joomla content, you still need one of those CMS's for CiviCRM.  You could install a new Joomla server and then copy CiviCRM to it (https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/misc/switch-servers/) or you could just delete the unneeded content from Joomla.

However, it sounds like your main issue is with CiviCRM reports rather than Joomla.  The CiviCRM database and code need to be running at the same version level otherwise you will get various errors.  I'd start by upgrading to the latest CiviCRM version on your current server - see https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/joomla/  Basically you update the CiviCRM code first then run the update scripts to make the necessary changes to the database.  Make sure you take a backup before starting the upgrade.

Comment: Thanks Aidan, i'll try that. Maybe i was trying to over complicate things.